# Minimum pair-wise XOR of elements from two sets

Tags: complexity-theory, sets, xor

I have two sets, $A$ and $B$, which both contain a large amount of hashed values. 
What is the most efficient way of computing:

$$\min_{i,j} A_i \otimes B_j$$

Comment: Hint: What is the smallest possible pair-wise XOR value? Can you think of an efficient way to find a pair that produces this value?

Comment: Well, the minimum is clearly 0, so I'm not sure where your hint is leading exactly. My guess would be to build a trie for B, and then check how far we can go down that trie with the complement of each element of A.

Comment: Sounds like you have an answer.  Is there a reason you've rejected that?  If you're asking whether it is possible to do better, it would be useful to [edit] the question describe the best algorithm you know of and analyze its running time.

Comment: What is “large”? 100? A million? A billion?

Comment: It would be totally easy if both arrays were sorted.